# Joining lines and text together (and a grey footnote) in a new environment for grey text

Tags: color, page-breaking, footnotes

I defined an environment called bewertung that's delimeted by two lines. I observe three problems I can not solve:

1. Pagebreaks after the first line (page 1 of MWE PDF).
2. Pagebreaks before the second line (page 2 of MWE PDF).
3. Grey footnotes if the grey paragraph within bewertung breaks (page 3 of MWE PDF).

To solve 1 and 2 I played around with `\nopagebreak`, `needspace.sty`, `@endparpenalty=10000`, `\clubpenalty=10000`, `\nobreak` and `\@afterheading`. But I had no success. I also found the corresponding UK-FAQ that did not help.

For problem 3 I tried to redefine `\footnote` with an explicit color definition. But it didn't work neither.

Here's a MWE. Actually `multicol` and `\vspace` are not needed to produce the problems, but it may be of interest for choosing the right solution.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{%
  ,multicol%
  ,blindtext
  ,xcolor
  ,fnpos
%  ,needspace
}

\newenvironment{bewertung}%
{%
  \noindent\textcolor{black!50}{\rule[-12pt]{\linewidth}{1pt}}%  
  \begin{multicols}{2}%
    \color{black!50}\sffamily\small%
    \noindent\ignorespaces%
}%
{%
  \end{multicols}%
  \noindent\textcolor{black!50}{\rule[15pt]{\linewidth}{1pt}}%
  \vspace{-\parskip}%
  \vspace{-12pt}%
}{\ignorespacesafterend}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\blindtext\footnote{\blindtext}

\vspace{25\baselineskip}

\begin{bewertung}
  \blindtext
\end{bewertung}

foo\footnote{Footnote}\vspace{22\baselineskip}

\begin{bewertung}
  \blindtext
\end{bewertung}

\blindtext\footnote{Grey footnote}\vspace{27\baselineskip}

\begin{bewertung}
  \blindtext
\end{bewertung}
\end{document}
```

[PDF of the MWE](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18529526/bewertung-lua.pdf)

Any suggestions how to solve these problems?

Comment: Try adding `\penatly10000\par` or `\\*` after the first line.

Comment: I tried both, but none of them solved the problem.

Comment: Just to be clear, is it acceptable for the box to break across pages if there is text before each line?

Comment: Yes, it is, AFAICS.

Comment: What is acceptable then? Is one line of text enough before the final line enough?

Comment: It's not nice but in any case it's better than a page break before the final line.

Answer (score 1):

The following code seems to do what you want. I rewrote the box from scratch (more for ease of understanding on my part). The important bit is I have used `minipage` in order to make sure that the box can never be broken across the page.

Also, to solve the grey footnote problem, I've just used `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` to make sure that the text for the footnote is defined outside of the grey text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{multicol}



\newenvironment{bewertung}{\medskip{\setlength{\multicolsep}{0pt}%
\color{black!50}%
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}%
{\sffamily Title of the frame}\rule{\linewidth-\widthof{Title of the frame}}{0.4pt}%
\begin{multicols}{2}\noindent}
{\end{multicols}\vspace{1ex}%
\hrule%
\end{minipage}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{bewertung}
\blindtext\footnotemark[1]
\end{bewertung}
\footnotetext[1]{Footnote text}

\begin{bewertung}
\blindtext\footnotemark[2]
\end{bewertung}
\footnotetext[2]{Footnote text}

\begin{bewertung}
\blindtext\footnotemark[3]
\end{bewertung}
\footnotetext[3]{Footnote text}

\begin{bewertung}
\blindtext\footnotemark[4]
\end{bewertung}
\footnotetext[4]{Footnote text}
\end{document}
```

[image: picture of the above code output]
[image: picture of the above code output]

EDIT:

New code using mdframed that breaks text. Unfortunately this does not prevent ending lines on it's own, but `mdframed` gives out a warning when this happens, which allows the user to fix it manually without trawling through the pdf to find it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{calc}

\newmdenv[leftline=false,%
    rightline=false,%
    topline=false,%
    frametitle={Title of the frame \rule{\linewidth-\widthof{Title of the frame }}{0.4pt}},%
    frametitlerule=false,%
    linecolor=black!50,%
    fontcolor=black!50,%
    frametitlefont=\color{black!50},%
    footnoteinside=false,%
    leftmargin=0pt,%
    innerleftmargin=0pt,%
    rightmargin=0pt,%
    innerrightmargin=0pt%
    ]{bewertung}


\begin{document}

\begin{bewertung}
\blindtext\footnotemark[1]
\end{bewertung}

\begin{bewertung}
\blindtext\footnotemark[1]
\end{bewertung}

\vspace{12em}
\begin{bewertung}
\blindtext\footnotemark[1]
\end{bewertung}

\footnotetext[1]{Footnote text}
\end{document}
```

[image: image of above code]
[image: image of above code 2]

Comment: Unfortunately, the position of the title is important. According the footnotes, there's a misunderstanding. I do not want grey footnotes! It happens when bewertung breaks within one of its paragraphs. But footnotes should always be black.

Comment: I redid the answer without mdframed to get the title right, using a minipage to ensure that the box can never be broken across the page.

Comment: Mostly it's necessary that the box breaks across the page …

Comment: Thank you very much! I will use your mdframed code since it solves the footnote problem and is more elegant. But it does not solve my problem with page breaks after or before lines. In my real life document are three pages with single lines that I even can't fix with \enlargethispage. It seems I have to rephrase some parts …

Comment: Today I tested the mdframed code in my real life document and some footnotes are still printed grey. Quite strange.

Comment: And you did this using `\footnotetext`? Did you place `\footnotetext` in a grey area? That might cause the problem.

Comment: Sorry for the delay! No, I didn't use \footnotetext. I just did not realize that it's part of the solution.

Comment: Yes, `footnotetext` is very handy in these kinds of situations! I use it mostly to avoid complications with tables and to allow one footnote to cover multiple columns. Glad that it works!